# Как сделать поиск файлов по шаблону?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, поиск

Есть код:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("//")
    for file in files:
        if file in fnmatch.filter(files,"*"+word+"*"):print(os.path.join(root,file))
```

Код нормально находит файл по указанному шаблону.

Как сделать такой поиск по нескольким словам?

Например, чтобы 'кот','собака'.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал функцию для поиска по регулярным выражениям:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

def glob_re(path, regex="", glob_mask="**/*", inverse=False):
    p = Path(path)
    if inverse:
        res = [str(f) for f in p.glob(glob_mask) if not re.search(regex, str(f))]
    else:
        res = [str(f) for f in p.glob(glob_mask) if re.search(regex, str(f))]
    return res
```

пример:

```
res = glob_re(r"/starting_path/to", regex="(?:кот|собака)")
```

PS по умолчанию используется маска `glob_mask="**/*"`, благодаря которой поиск будет осуществляться рекурсивно во всех поддиректориях. Если искать нужно только в текущей директории, тогда надо явно указать `glob_mask="*"`

Answer (score 1):

что мешает в лоб забубенить?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("//")
    for file in files:
        for word in words:
            if file in fnmatch.filter(files, f"*{word}*"):print(os.path.join(root,file))
```

ну или найти все файлы, а потом уже регулярными выражениями выбрать то, что вам нужно

Comment: Так выдает ошибку NameError: name 'word' is not defined

Comment: так вы определите - `words = ['кошка', 'собака']`

Comment: Все words определил но ошибка все равно остаётся.

Comment: Извиняюсь, поправил все нормально за работало.

Comment: Подскажите ещё такой момент если будет сложный шаблон слово типа Арао1333-37...будет такое работать?

Comment: должен - у вас же стоит `*`, т.е. любые символы

Comment: Да все нормально функционирует, единственное поиск только медленно идёт.

Comment: потому что делается многократно, поэтому я и предложил второй вариант - вы ищите все файлы и уже потом фильтруете по названиям - для разных шаблонов этот способ должен быть более быстрым

Comment: А примерного кода это варианта у вас нет?

Comment: вам надо смотреть в строку "питон поиск файлов через регулярные выражения"  что-то типа такого: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293968/how-do-i-search-directories-and-find-files-that-match-regex

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо занаводку)